# scala Ywarn-all usage

Tags: scala, scalac

I'm trying to use scala compiler Y warnings, but I don't think I'm doing it right. In the example below, nums is unused, hence I'd expect -Ywarn-value-discard to print a warning for that. 
There are two if conditions, one nested inside the other. The child if's condition is exact opposite of parents', hence anything inside it is dead code. But -Ywarn-dead-code doesn't warn against that. 
Could anyone please suggest what I might be doing wrong? Any pointers would be appreciated.

```
object DeadCodeWarn{
  def main( args: Array[ String ] ) {
    val nums = 1 to 100
    //There should be a warning for squares
    //as its a non-unit expression thats not
    //used in any computation. Y-warn-value-discard
    val squares = nums.map( x => x * x ) 

    if( nums.length == 100 ){
      println( "should be printed" )
      if( nums.length !=100 )
      {
        //-Ywarn-dead-code
        println( "Dead code, so should be warned against" )
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`$scalac -Xlint -Ywarn-all DeadCodeWarn.scala` succeeds silently.

Answer (score 4):

### -Ywarn-value-discard

The value isn't discarded, it's assigned to the `val`!
The problem is that the `val` is unused

With code:

```
package foo

case class Foo(x: Int) {
  def foo: Int = {
    val y = 2;
    x
  }
}
```

I get with scalac 2.11.5 and `-Ywarn-unused`:

```
[warn] /.../foo.scala:5: local val in method foo is never used
[warn]     val y = 2;
```

---

### -Ywarn-dead-code

It's easy to write the counter-example(s) where the *common* logic doesn't work:

```
// Evil mutable class
class Arrayish {
  private var x: Int = 100
  def length(): Int = {
    val res = x
    x += 1
    res
  }
}

def test(nums: Arrayish): Unit =
  if (nums.length == 100) {
    println( "should be printed" )
    if (nums.length != 100) {
      println("Dead code, so should be warned against")
    }
  }
```

Dead code is run:

```
scala> test(new Arrayish())
should be printed
Dead code, so should be warned against
```

---

Or

```
class NonEqual {
  def ==(x: Int): Boolean = true
  def !=(x: Int): Boolean = true
}

class NaNLength {
  val length: NonEqual = new NonEqual
}

def test2(nums: NaNLength): Unit =
  if (nums.length == 100) {
    println("should be printed")
    if (nums.length != 100) {
      println("Dead code, so should be warned against")
    }
  }
```

Dead code is run as well:

```
scala> test2(new NaNLength)
should be printed
Dead code, so should be warned against
```

---

Scalac compiler isn't smart enough to distinguish well behaving and not-so-well behaving cases.

---

If you are going to submit the bug / feature-request, mention example like:

```
def test3(nums: Array[Int]): Unit = {
  if (true) {
    println("should be printed")
    if (false) {
      println("Dead code, so should be warned against")
    }
  }
}

def test4(nums: Array[Int]): Unit = {
  val hundred = nums.length == 100
  if (hundred) {
    println("should be printed")
    if (!hundred) {
      println("Dead code, so should be warned against")
    }
  }
}
```

Seems that scalac dead code reporter isn't as polished as e.g. Java. I hope scalac does optimise these examples properly though, it shouldn't be too complicated.

Comment: Sorry, could you explain what you're saying about unused code? The value `squares` is not being used (discarded by me), so shouldn't it have been warned against?

Comment: @user247077 AFAIK according to [2.11.x Warnings.scala](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.11.x/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/settings/Warnings.scala) the `-Ywarn-unused`, `-Ywarn-value-discard` and `-Ywarn-dead-code` have to be specified explicitly. `-Ywarn-all` isn't supported by `2.11.5`: `bad option: '-Ywarn-all'`. [`2.10`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.10.x/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/settings/Warnings.scala) doesn't seem to have `-Ywarn-unused`, probably there aren't related diagnostic code either.

Comment: Maybe note that `-Ywarn-value-discard` is for when values are discarded to `Unit`. e.g. `val x: Unit = 0`

Comment: @phadej I do agree that there could be side-effecting code, but if this is coming from their own immutable collection class, then it should be handled even for a length. Even more, if you look at the code, they do have an `isPure` method that theoretically checks for this case.

Comment: @JustinPihony the [TODO: proper analysis](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/3d76836bc81c3ec183e83ee186e447ff212507d0/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/backend/opt/DeadCodeElimination.scala#L446) isn't very promising. In general it's very hard problem, so it's easier to take conservative path. After all JVM JIT optimisations will effectively throw away unused branches. Yes it won't trigger diagnostics, but maybe it's job for auxiliary tools, not compiler itself (e.g. clang has separate static analyser people can build own tools upon etc.).

Comment: @phadej I agree that it is a difficult problem and thus why an open ticket will probably be low on the list of things to fix. I was just pointing the pieces out for clarification purposes.

Answer (score 1):

After some toying around with the code, it appears that this is simply not a case where dead code is caught. I will see about continuing to peruse the [compiler code itself](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/3d76836bc81c3ec183e83ee186e447ff212507d0/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/backend/opt/DeadCodeElimination.scala), however upon review it seems that dead code is eliminated. Upon elimination is when it seems to emit the warning. So, if you review something as simple as

```
def foo = {return 1; 1}
```

You will see that the final code is simply to return 1 and not even emit the second 1. However, if you take a look at the final code of this nested `if` you will see that the second `if` is not eliminated.

Go ahead and submit a bug, although I'm not sure what kind of priority this would have.

Comment: Let me know if you are going to submit. If not, I will :)

Comment: I'm not lazy: http://pastebin.com/UPGDdH74 but I don't feel qualified enough, so can you do it please?

Comment: Forgot to tag you in my previous comment. Could you post back here if you submit the issue? Thanks

Comment: First I took it to the mailing list to verify it: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-internals/lLIfdtsBNfY